# How to fix mbr if I can't get to the cmd or terminal, and I deleted grub?

Tags: windows-7, linux, multi-boot, mbr

***Problem***

---

I removed the GRUB, BUT in Windows disk management, I started to delete the first (of four) Linux partitions and after I got tired of waiting, I restarted the PC during the deletion process.

---

***Setup***

---

I am using a dual-boot setup. Linux + Windows, until I attempted to remove Linux

***Tried solutions***

---

Now, I can't fix MBR by booting Windows -> typing commands in cmd because I can't get to cmd, I can't get past starting Windows. When I try to boot Ubuntu from live USB and select try Ubuntu, it gets stuck loading. If I try to install Ubuntu, it gives my a bunch of errors like: 'kernel panic - not syncing', 'killing process' and errors like that go for hours! I booted GParted live, same thing.

I tried safe mode, system repair, it can't boot anything! I've Googled for hours, I can not find someone with my type of problem, so I can't solve the problem like they did (which is - they booted into Windows and fixed it through cmd).

Comment: Boot to the Windows 7 installation media, you will be able to run the command within the WinRE, contained on the media itself.

Comment: I just told you that I can't boot into windows installation media! It loads, then it gets stuck at 'starting windows'

Comment: Your question does not contain the words "installation" or "media" in it.  If you said it, then it was stated in a way, that wasn't clear.  I consider the installation menu and the recovery media contained on the installation media to be two seperate functions.  I suggest you spend some time to provide some clarity to you question to avoid comments like this.

Answer (score 0):

You need a Windows Installation Disc/USB.

First Method:

1. Boot into the Disc/USB and then Continue
2. Press SHIFT+F10
3. Type in: bootrec.exe /FixMbr
4. If it was Successful, restart your Computer.
5. And Welcome back to Windows!

If you still can't boot, then i would Suggest you, to Reinstall Windows (Backup your Data with the Command Prompt on the Disc/USB).

Comment: I'm sorry, did anyone read the words I wrote below the question. I apologize if I didn't express myself better, but english is not my native language and I don't know how to explain it better. Your solution can work, i've seen it when I googled it, but it won't work because I CAN NOT REACH/GO/GET TO cmd! When i boot from usb, it loads, but it doesn't show the menu where I can choose date and so on because it gets stuck on 'starting windows'! You know how you can choose date, time, languge when you reinstall windows? It doesn not show me that "menu" or how do you call that..

Comment: @ŽelimZnatiViše That was not in your question. Remember that comments are _not_ for anything important, as some people do not see them, and they can be deleted at any time anyway.

Answer (score 0):

I HIGHLY recommend fixing the problem with a boot-repair. I have had the same problems as you and this was what I used to fix it.

Next time you want to uninstall linux, just use this disk as it features an easy to use 'uninstall OS' option.

Download link;
https://sourceforge.net/p/boot-repair/home/Home/

:D

To set up a grub super disk, use Ubootnet, win32disk imager or some other disk imaging software, and create a bootable usb. Alternatively you can use a disk if you have some laying around.

Im guessing you should know this process since you did install linux.

Once inside of Super grub disk, a 'fix boot' menu should pop up. Use this, and make sure to look at settings like 'fix windows' and 'fix mbr'.

**I would like to mention however,**
that if you cant boot in to ANY live USB, or any OS then you have serious problems. Under no circumstance should you motherboard bios boot stop working for the problem you have asked, and if this is the case, then the problem could be a lot worse then indicated.

Hope I helped,

~Tealkine

Comment: Thank you Tealkine! I would try this as soon as possible and I sure hope this will fix my problem! Anyeay, I'll let you know if it worked or not. Thanks again :)

Comment: @ŽelimZnatiViše Your welcome, if the problem persits than I can try to help you :D

Comment: Hi, I tried evertything and the only thing I think could work is grub rescue because I manage to get to grub rescue. How can I delete linux partitions or install grub again when I'm in grub rescue?

Comment: @ŽelimZnatiViše Grub rescue, typically, isnt a gateway to fixing your computer if you have deleted grub. I would reccommend booting this USB that I have reccommended, and looking at the GParted that is provided with it. Ask yourself. Is the partition size ok? Is the used size ok?

It would also be very helpful if you could provide the response to what happened when you attempted to use said fix above.

Comment: I download supergrubdisk but It doesn't have GParted in it. It has the following:

Comment: Languages, detect and show boot methods, enable grub2's RAID, Enable all native disk drivers, Boot manually..., Extra GRUB2 functionallity, print devices/partitions, color ON/OFF, Exit.

Comment: I tried everyone of those, and still can't fix the problem. I booted rescatux now end it gave me: 'error: symbol grub isprint not found. Entering rescue mode... grub rescue>

Comment: @ŽelimZnatiViše I am actually the biggest idiot and tard. https://sourceforge.net/p/boot-repair/home/Home/ < there you go. That will boot a custom linux OS that features many of the boot-repair solutions. I am so sorry for wasting your time. I havent used either of the programs in a while and got them mixed up.

Comment: Never mind, so when I download this, I should have the options you mentioned? I'll download this now, and I'll get back when I boot it. I really appreciate your help!

Comment: It won't boot the boot-repair-disk... It gives me the following:/scripts/init-top/framebuffer: line 125: can't fork. /init: /scripts/init-top/ORDER: line 11: can't fork...... drm_kms_helper: panic occured, switching back to text console. It gives me these errors after I choose the language and after I selected the 64-bit session. Is there anything else I can do? If I replace the hard drivw that I have now with the new one, would that fix the problem?

Comment: @ŽelimZnatiViše Well this is an interesting scenario, and unfortunatly falls outside my expertise. I do not know whether replacing the harddrive will fix the problem, but you can try it.

Comment: I'm sorry to hear that, but thank you for trying to help :)